# exampleの追加方法について

Tags: spresense

こんにちは、SPRESENSEボードを使ってQZSS（みちびき）の災危通報を受信しようとしています。
まずはGNSSの受信をしているか確認するために
GNSSのexampleを追加しようとしています。

既にSPRESENSE SDKのビルドを行い、hello world　ができることも確認しましたが、
GNSSのexampleを追加でコンフィギュレーションや
ビルドしようとしても次のような表示がされてしまいます。

```
/bin/sh: 1: kconfig-conf: not found
make[1]: *** [do_olddefconfig] エラー 127
make: *** [olddefconfigkernel] エラー 2
Post process failed. 512
Try 'make distcleankernel' first.
```

sdkのディレクトリでmake distcleankernelやmake cleanを行いましたが
変化ありませんでした。
当方初心者のため何か基本的な見落としがあるのかも知れませんが
ご回答いただければ幸いです。

Comment: すみません、githubのSpresense SDK build instructionsのPrerequisitesに書いてあるコマンドを実行したらうまくいったみたいです。お騒がせしました

Comment: kuninamiさん、スタック・オーバーフローでは後から自己解決した場合自己回答ができ、また、推奨しています！　少し時間が経てば自分の回答を承認することもできますので、よろしければ自己回答をお願いいたします :)

Answer (score 1):

問題の原因はコンフィギュレーションのツールが
インストールされていなかったことが原因だったようです。
githubのSpresense SDK build instructionsのPrerequisitesに
書いてあるコマンドを実行したところ、
ツールがインストールされコンフィギュレーションできるようになりました。

URL:https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense